# Como impedir o hover de alterar as outras divs?

Tags: div, css-hover

Meu hover faz a div aumentar de largura e altura mas isso acaba fazendo as outras divs ao redor se afastarem por causa do espaço na página. Já tentei modificar as outras ao ativar o hover de cada uma, meio que pra equilibrar tudo mas não consegui.

```
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Memory Game</h1>
    <h2>Click on the "SPREAD" button to start.</h2>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div><br>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div><br>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div><br>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
main {
height: 800px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```

}

```
.card {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
height: 184.2px;
width: 280px;
background: rgba(69, 5, 153, 0.884);
cursor: pointer;
```

}

```
.card:hover {
border-style: solid;
border-color: rgb(226, 241, 237);
height: 194.2px;
width: 290px;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É necessário manter o posicionamento original de cada card, mesmo com o hover. Para isso eu criei o filho no exemplo, ele que é afetado pelo efeito de tamanho.

```css
main {
height: 800px;
text-align: center;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.card {
display: inline-block;
margin: 10px;
height: 184.2px;
width: 280px;
background: rgba(69, 5, 153, 0.884);
cursor: pointer;
}
.filho {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: 1s;
}
.filho:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Memory Game</h1>
    <h2>Click on the "SPREAD" button to start.</h2>
</header>
<main>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="filho"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="filho"></div> 
    </div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div><br>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div><br>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div>
    <div class="card"></div><br>
</main>
```